# post data from datagrid to server (JSON)

Tags: c#, jqgrid

I want to make use of jqgrid / inline edit and want to:

- inline edit the data
- when done, user clicks on save and the (changed) data rows are send te the server

I have tried, but no results. Please see jsiddle here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function postAllGridData() {
        // TODO : JSON request to server + reload grid
        alert('code here');
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Gc7K/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2Gc7K/2/.

In the code I set selected row in inline editing mode and save previous editing row (if any exist)

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    if (rowid && rowid !== lastSel) { 
        $(this).jqGrid("saveRow", lastSel); 
        lastSel = rowid; 
    }
    $(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, true); 
}
```

After the user click on "save current grid data to server" the current editing row (if any exist) will be saved and then *current* data from the grid will be saved in the variables `gridData`. After then one can send the data to the server by separate jQuery.ajax call. In the simplest way I serialized the object to JSON string using `JSON.stringify` and displayed the results with respect of `alert`:

```js
$("#postAllGridData").click(function () {
    var gridData;
    $grid.jqGrid("saveRow", lastSel)
    gridData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
    alert("data:\n" + JSON.stringify(gridData));
});
```

I used `rowNum: 10000`. So that no local paging of data are used. The code will work in the same way even if local paging were used. In the case one should just specify the value of `rowNum` less as the number of rows and add top pager (by adding `toppager: true` option) or add empty `<div>` (like `<div id="mypager"></div>`) to the page and use `pager: "#mypager"` option.

**UPDATED**: One can modify the above code to the following

```
$("#postAllGridData").click(function () {
    var gridData,
        // get ids of edited rows
        editedRows = $.map($grid.find(">tbody>tr[editable]"),
                           function(elem){
                               return $(elem).attr("id");
                           });
    $grid.jqGrid("saveRow", lastSel);
    alert("data:\n" + JSON.stringify(editedRows));
    // get data of edited rows
    gridData = $.grep($grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"), function(row) {
        return $.inArray(row.id, editedRows) >= 0;
    });
    alert("data:\n" + JSON.stringify(gridData));
});
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2Gc7K/5/). I used `jQuery.map` to get ids of rows which was *edited* (even non changed) and `jQuery.grep` to filter `data` to the rows which was edited.

The most common code will be

```
$("#postAllGridData").click(function () {
    var gridData, indexes = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "_index"),
        idPrefix = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
        // get ids of edited rows
        indexesOfEditedRows = $.map($grid.find(">tbody>tr[editable]"),
                                    function(elem) {
                                        return indexes[$.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, $(elem).attr("id"))];
                                    });
    // get data of edited rows
    gridData = $.grep($grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"), function(row, i) {
        return $.inArray(i, indexesOfEditedRows) >= 0;
    });
    alert("data:\n" + JSON.stringify(gridData));
});
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2Gc7K/10/). Because we still use existence of `editable` attribute to filter the data it's important that the method works only in case of displaying all rows on one page. In case of paging one will have to save ids or indexes of edited rows on the current page before go to another page. One can use `onPaging` callback in the case. As the result we get the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2Gc7K/13/ with the following code

```
var lastSel, indexesOfOldEditedRows = [], $grid = $("#list4");

$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    onPaging: function () {
        var $self = $(this),
            indexes = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "_index"),
            idPrefix = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
            indexesOfEditedRows;
        $self.jqGrid("saveRow", lastSel); 
        indexesOfEditedRows = $.map($self.find(">tbody>tr[editable]"),
                                    function(elem) {
                                        return indexes[$.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix,
                                                                         $(elem).attr("id"))];
                                    });
        $.merge(indexesOfOldEditedRows, indexesOfEditedRows);
    }
});


$("#postAllGridData").click(function () {
    var gridData, indexes = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "_index"),
        idPrefix = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
        indexesOfEditedRows;
        // get ids of edited rows
    $grid.jqGrid("saveRow", lastSel);
    indexesOfEditedRows = $.map($grid.find(">tbody>tr[editable]"),
                                function(elem) {
                                    return indexes[$.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, $(elem).attr("id"))];
                                });
    $.merge(indexesOfOldEditedRows, indexesOfEditedRows);
    // get data of edited rows
    gridData = $.grep($grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"), function(row, i) {
        return $.inArray(i, indexesOfOldEditedRows) >= 0;
    });
    alert("data:\n" + JSON.stringify(gridData));
});
```

Comment: Thanx, you made it look so easy :) just wondering if you know a good way to find out if row 3,4,5 have changed from value that only this rows rows  are send to the server..? maybe jqgrid haves some default support for this?

Comment: @lordkain: You can use the fact that jqGrid set `editable` attribute to `<tr>` after editing. So if you can use `$.map($grid.find(">tbody>tr[editable]"),function(elem){return $(elem).attr("id")})` to get ids of edited rows. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2Gc7K/4/

Comment: Thank you again once more.. This is exactly wat I wanted to archieve!