# jqGrid checkbox not saving

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with a column that contains a checkbox. I've noticed that when the user toggles the checkbox, jqGrid doesn't actually put the row into edit mode. So when the user clicks the save button the new value of the checkbox is not saved.

Is this the default behavior for checkboxes in jgGrid? What't the best way to make jqGrid saved the checkbox value?

Here is the jqGrid code:

```
var myGrid = jQuery("#myGrid");

myGrid.jqGrid({
    editurl: 'UpdateData',
    datatype: function (postdata) {
        //some code
    },
    height: "450",
    footerrow: false,
    userDataOnFooter: false,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000],
    sortname: 'SomeId',
    pager: '#footer',
    caption: "",
    colNames: ['Field1', 'Field2'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Col1', index: 'Col1', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: true, search: true },
        { name: 'MyCheckBox', index: 'MyCheckBox', hidden: false, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, search: true }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function (index) {
        myGrid.jqGrid('editRow', index, true);
    }
});

myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#footer',
    { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false },
    { closeAfterAdd: true }, // use default settings for edit
    { closeAfterAdd: true, left: ((document.body.clientWidth / 2) - 100), top: ((document.body.clientHeight / 2) - 50) }, // use default settings for add
    { },  // delete instead that del:false we need this
    { multipleSearch: false }, // enable the advanced searching
    { closeOnEscape: true} /* allow the view dialog to be closed when user press ESC key*/
);

myGrid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#footer',
{
    buttonicon: "none",
    caption: "Save",
    onClickButton: function () {
        //save the currently selected row
    }
})
```

I was thinking about using jQuery to attach a "change" handler to each checkbox that would put that row into edit mode when the user clicked the checkbox. Seems like a hack though and I wasn't sure how to properly identify the checkbox column in the grid (my example only shows one checkbox but the grid actually has two).

Does jqGrid support better checkbox behavior than this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you understand yourself now that your initial assumption that `formatter: "checkbox"` uses inline editing, if it was initialized with the option `formatoptions: { disabled: false }`, is wrong. jqGrid supports tree independent editing modes: cell editing, inline editing and form editing.

Formatting is just the form to display values of input data. One can, for example, display `0` and `1` (or `true` and `false`) values as `Yes` and `No` or as checked button or unchecked or as two different images or as cells in green and red or ... So the goal of formatter is constructing HTML fragments which will be placed in cells of the corresponding column.

Specially in case of usage `formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }` one should implement `click` handle which will makes some *additional* action, which you need, in case of changing the state of the checkbox. The best implementation of such behavior in my opinion can be written using `beforeSelectRow` callback. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935) shows what can be done in case of usage `datatype: "local"`. In the case there are internal parameters `_index` and `data` which holds the data. If you use another `datatype` value you have many implementation options. You can do for example almost the same, but save changed states of checkboxes in your custom array or object. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309828/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608648/315935) for additional information.

Some common remarks about the code which you posted. I strictly recommend you to avoid usage of `datatype` defined as function if you use `jQuery.ajax` internally. It's topically an origin of errors. jqGrid provides a lot of options which allows you to customize `jQuery.ajax` which makes jqGrid itself in case of usage `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`. There are `beforeProcessing` callback, `ajaxGridOptions` option, `jsonReader` which can use functions (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)), `jsonmap` property in `colModel`, which can be functions too and so on. I recommend you to use the features instead.

Additionally I would recommend you to add `gridview: true` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935)) and `autoencode: true` option in the grid and remove unneeded `index` properties from `colModel` and properties with *default values* `hidden: false`, `sortable: true`, `search: true`. It is strictly recommended to fill `id` (rowid) in the input data or use `key: true` for some column if the column already contains unique id value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and well thought out response. Unfortunately, I don't have enough jqGrid experience to follow everything you're saying. At this point I'm probably just going to use formatoptions: { disabled: true } and force the user to put the row into edit mode before checking a box. It would be nice if checking the box itself could put the row into edit mode but that's apparently not how it works.

Comment: @You are welcome! If you fill unsure yourself in jqGrid removing `formatoptions: { disabled: true }` will be probably the best choice. In any way the usage of simple options `gridview: true, autoencode: true` would be good. You should consider to remove exotic `datatype: function` and use standard `datatype` value.

Comment: Yeah, this is a project I inherited and I'm not sure why it's set up the way it is. The datatype function always looked pretty bizarre to me so I'm not surprised that you say it's a bad idea. Unfortunately there are dozens of grids and they all work that way. Maybe someday I'll get around to changing it.